# "There is a problem with the flow trigger" when import the solution inside the prodcution environment

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have an automated flow which which contains 3 trigger conditions as follow:-

```
@equals(length(split(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}'],'/')),int(parameters('CustomerFolderLocation (birchgol_CustomerFolderLocation)')))
@equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/{IsFolder}'],true)
@equals(endsWith(triggerOutputs()?['body/{Path}'],concat(parameters('PathToFolder (birchgol_PathToFolder)'),'/')),true)
```

[image]

The flow worked well on the Dev environment, but when i move it to the PROD environment inside the solution the flow will never get triggered and i will get this error:-

[image: johnjohn123_0-1694039461149.png]

Any advice why the workflow triggers are not working inside the PROD environment? the parameters inside trigger condition are referencing environment variables.